Is it possible to get imageio video iterator starting past the first frame?
Imageio user guide https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#read-or-iterate-frames-in-a-video shows examples of random access to video frames and a sequential iteration:
import imageio.v3 as iio

# read a single frame
frame = iio.imread(
    "imageio:cockatoo.mp4",
    index=42,
    plugin="pyav",
)

# iterate over large videos
for frame in iio.imiter("imageio:cockatoo.mp4", plugin="pyav"):
    print(frame.shape, frame.dtype)

On my PC, random access is an order of magnitude slower than access with a sequential iterator iio.imiter. Is there a way to get iio.imiter starting from an arbitrary frame, perhaps by using a parameter or a prior call to seek function? The seek doesn't have to be very accurate, as long as it is repeatable.

if (idk whether it can't) iio can't do it, you can use PyAV directly
